# Scaling external webpage within HTML Object tag without encountering CORS conflicts (Deformation acceptable)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple webpage that fades back and forth between the publicly embeddable mars rovers weather reports on a loop.

```html
<object data="https://mars.nasa.gov/layout/embed/image/mslweather/" width="1920" height="1080"></object>
<!-- comes out to 1920 x 679.25 -->

<object data="https://mars.nasa.gov/layout/embed/image/m20weather/" width="1920" height="1080"></object>
<!-- comes out to 1920 x 806.25-->
```

However, these two embedded pages return with slightly different heights.
I'd like to scale the contents of these to match heights.

If I had proper access, I'd simply navigate to the appropriate tag within the objects and modify the property. However, I don't have access to the internal documents.

Is there any way to scale the contents of these tags without needing to access the internal documents of the objects? Stretching and squashing the contents is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Give both the respective appropriate actual height - and then use `transform: scaleY(...)` to either scale one down to the height of the other, or the other way around ...?